# Outlook plugin issue with shared calendar improvements new Office 365 feature

Tags: outlook, office365, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

With my outlook plugin after enabling new "Shared Calendar Improvements" feature, I have observed getting wrong StoreID (actual user's calendar folder storeID instead of shared calendar folder's storeID) while creating meeting on the shared calendar.
This works well without enabling this new feature. I have tried with multiple calendars with/without this new feature enabled.

Below is the code which I am using.

```
object aptItemParent = aptItem.Parent;
folder = (MAPIFolder)aptItemParent;
storeId = folder.StoreID; ////If I try without shared calendar improvements feature on, it gives correct storeID of the shared calendar where meeting is getting created however, with that feature it gives wrong storeID (main calendar's storeID).
```

Can you please suggest if this is a known issue and any reference link of it? And is there any fix/workaround to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came to know from Microsoft team that this is a known issue from their end and the workaround is to disable shared calendar improvement features for now.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-plugin-issue-with-shared-calendar/6b897517-16fa-4d42-9445-2efc3080ca01

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the `EntryID` property value use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder).

Comment: Thanks! I think the approach I have should also work fine as we have AppointmentItem object from that particular shared calendar so we should get the storeId of that particular folder which it resides. It works since many years only issue started happening with this new feature - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-enable-and-disable-the-outlook-calendar-sharing-updates-c3aec5d3-55ce-4cea-84b0-80aab6d8dc26 so suspecting a bug with this new feature.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Outlook caches shared default folders in the primary account's OST file, so no wonder the store id will be that of the primary account owner.

Try to turn off the delegate mailbox caching in your Exchange account properties ("Download shared folders" chdckbox).

Comment: Thanks!! I believe this happens without "Shared calendar improvement" feature as well then also it works perfectly fine since many years. Issue is only after this new feature - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-enable-and-disable-the-outlook-calendar-sharing-updates-c3aec5d3-55ce-4cea-84b0-80aab6d8dc26

Comment: So have you tried to disable caching?